# How can I insert hyperlinks into HTML via a search/replace operation without inadvertently nesting links?

Tags: c#, html

I have a string of HTML.  Inside it are "magic words," which I need to replace as links, using C#.  This is a string replace operation, not a DOM parse. So...

```
This is a magic word.
```

...needs to become...

```
This is a <a href="/link.html">magic</a> word.
```

It's a fairly easy replace operation, except, what do I do if the word is already linked in the input.  So if this is my input:

```
This is a <a href="/link.html">magic</a> word.
```

I end up with this:

```
This is a <a href="/link.html"><a href="/link.html">magic</a></a> word.
```

That might be easy to get around, by searching for whitespace or brackets or something, but what about this:

```
This is a <a href="/link.html">crazy magic stuff</a> word.
```

The string " magic " is free-floating there in the middle, and I'll get this:

```
This is a <a href="/link.html">crazy <a href="/link.html">magic</a> stuff</a> word
```

What would be the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you're parsing your strings or DOM, but it's fairly simple. Just whenever you encounter a `<a` you skip everything until you encounter a `</a>`, then continue parsing and replacing your words. You can do this because you can't have a link inside a link.

And to make your words as links you just have to close the `a` tag after each word, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Sorry -- I clarified in the post.  This is a C# string replace operation.

Comment: Then you should ask it as a C# question since it's a string parse in C# and not really HTML. I don't know that language, but maybe you can understand the pseudocode and use it in your language. This is how I'd do it in any language unless you got other restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this should **never** be used to parse HTML, but if you need to achieve what you describe with a String replacement method, what about something like the following?

```
private static string Linkify(string phrase, string word)
{
    int wordIndex = phrase.IndexOf(word);
    int linkBeginIndex = phrase.IndexOf("<a");
    int linkEndIndex = phrase.IndexOf("</a>");

    if(linkBeginIndex == -1 || !(wordIndex > linkBeginIndex && wordIndex < linkEndIndex))
    {
        phrase = phrase.Replace(word, String.Format("<a href='/link.html'>{0}</a>", word));
    }

    return phrase;
}
```

Here's a link to a DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2e5Uh2

This is not a flexible implementation, since the text might contain `<a`, for example, and that wouldn't work. We are assuming this is for the very simple scenario you suggested.

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for and I'll edit my answer.